# Upgrading app to support ios5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios4

I wish to update an app to support ios5 and up. CUrrently the app supports ios5 and below and i was wondering what the implications of setting the build to be ios5 and above would be to customers still using the ios4 app on ios4. Would app store refuse to download the ios5 and up app update and complain to the user to update their os to 5? what exactly would happen in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Store would simply refuse to upgrade the app and tell the user to upgrade to iOS 5 (or 6).
That's the standard policy, so that if you have an old iOS you can still use your old apps.

As a side note, the cumulated market share of iOS 5 and up is [more than 90%](http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/), so you won't have to worry about supporting old versions. Most iOS devs I know are moving on or already have.